# Setting parent's div height of resizable image

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div style="height: auto">
    <img style='position: absolute; left:0; right:0; margin: -115px auto 0; overflow: hidden;' src='img_url' />
</div>

<div style="background: #ea9027; height: 150px;">
    etst text
</div>
```

When I'm resizing the browser, image is being resized also (which is what I want, I don't want to have specific height and width, I want it to be 100% of the width of the browser screen). But when I'm resizing the browser, the distance between two divs become bigger. How can I fix it? Do I need to use javascript for this? `height:auto` in the first div doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe viewport units would be useful in your case? https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: Please use CSS-classes, and not inline styling. It makes it easier for us to help you, if you give us a helpful overview.

Comment: if you set position absolute on the image , it's height is not being considered when calculating the height of the parent div. You could use javascript to solve this

Comment: can you provide your working code in demo or fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it pretty easily with javascript:

```
<script>
    function resize() {
        var img = document.getElementById('imageId'); 
        document.getElementById("imageIdDiv").style.height = img.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = function() {
        resize();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use javascript, you can simply use `vh: 100%;`
This is viewport height property in css and it works really good.